# iOS9～ のiPadでsizeClassをRegularに設定したのに反映されない

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iphone

ipadではこのレイアウトを変更しよう とsizeClassを縦横Regularに指定した項目があるのですが、エミュレーター・実機共に反応してくれず、何故かany anyの設定が反映されてしまいます
iOS8.1のシミュレーター、iOS8.4の実機では正常にRegular Regularの設定が反映される事を確認しました。

xcodeのプロジェクトはこちらとなります
http://fushi.x0.com/php_system/20160117-stackoverflow-question/xibTest2.zip

xibで定義した二つのビュー(AaView と BView)があり
AaViewはViewController上から

```
class AaViewController : UIViewController{
    var childView : AaView?
    var bView : BView?
    override func loadView() {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;
        if let view = UINib(nibName: "AaView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil).first as? AaView{
            self.view = view;
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.childView = self.view as! AaView!
        self.bView =  BView(frame: (UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.bounds)!)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.addSubview(self.bView! )
    }
}
```

の様に、定義し

BViewは

```
class BView: UIView {
@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
override init(frame: CGRect) { // for using CustomView in code
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.commonInit()
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { // for using CustomView in IB
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.commonInit()
}
private func commonInit(  ) {
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("BView", owner: self, options: nil)
    contentView.frame = self.bounds
    self.addSubview(contentView)
}
```

}

の様に定義しました。

sizeClassがおかしい以外はAもBも表示されており、iphone 6Plus iOS 9.2では正常にanyのラベルのみ表示されます。(左上にB-any、右下にA-any)
[image: 左上と右下にanyのラベルがある]

ところが、ipad2 iOS9.0/ipad air2 iOS 9.2ではA-Regularは狙い通り表示されるのですが、BについてはB-anyが表示されてしまいます。レイアウトの指定方法をミスって位置がズレてしまっていますが・・。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

これらのラベルはxCode上では
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
の様に定義されており、reg regは縦横共にRegularの時のみ表示
anyは縦横共にanyの時 ただしRegularの時は除く という指定です。

AaView、BView共に同じ指定方法です。

AaViewに関しては望み通りの表示がされているのですが、BViewについて何故かSizeClassが反映されません。
パラメーター、設定不足等ありましたら教えて頂けますでしょうか

xcodeのバージョンは7.2となります

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4):

BViewにSizeClassが反映されない原因ですが、AaViewControllerのviewDidLoad()において、以下のコードでbViewをUIWindowの直下に追加しているのが原因と思われます。

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.addSubview(self.bView!)
```

該当箇所を普通にviewに追加するように書き換えれば、正常に動作するようになるかと思われます。

```
view.addSubview(bView!)
```

『なぜ、UIWindowの直下にViewを追加するとSizeClassが正常に動作しなくなるか？』ですが、この場合、traitCollectionDidChangeが呼び出されなくなるところまではわかりましたが・・・　詳細な理由は不明です。